# is there a formula for the sum of n'th powers

Tags: calculus

is there a formula for this sum

> $\sum_{i=1}^{k} {i^{n}}$

i know of the formula for square and cubic sums,

> $\sum_{i=1}^{k} {i^{2}}$,
>   $\sum_{i=1}^{k} {i^{3}}$

but i couldn't find a correlation between then in order to get a generic formula for the n'th power,
does one exist?
i couldnt find one online by googling around

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: yep thats what i have been looking for, i bit more then i can chew on this one...

Comment: Waht you look for are the generalized harmonic numbers. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number